# How to train a Faster RCNN model using tensorflow 2.0 api

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am new to the object detection field, currently want to build a faster-rcnn model to recognize multiple objects within an image.

I have went through several tutorials including the official tutorial from TensorFlow GitHub [https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md#installation], roboflow and online tutorial such as [https://pub.towardsai.net/training-faster-r-cnn-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api-with-a-custom-dataset-88dd525666fd]. But none of them works for me, mostly due to package version conflict and lack of instructions.

Therefore, I would like to ask where can I find a proper guide or tutorial for building a faster-rcnn model?

Comment: You should formulate a repeatable and barebones example and make your goals measurable by some metric (total training time, total inference time, etc). It would also help in answering your question to know what you currently have working and what you tried that didn't work. Having some notion of your end use-case, while not necessary for answering your question, could help us identify possible avenues of exploration for you.

I don't think I can do much more than pass this advice and tell you to look into YoLo v5 (you only look once v5) as I'm no expert in this domain.

Comment: Why faster-rcnn specifically? That model is quite old, slow, and not-accurate compared to many of the newer ones. I'd recommend YOLOv5; it's really easy to use: https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov5-on-a-custom-dataset/

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this very informative tutorial https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model. You can use FasterRCNN from Tf2 detection Zoo https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md instead of EfficientDet0.